# wp_verify_nonce() why return false?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin-menu

I was to tried create theme options admin page (without settings API)

in this code I'd like to know why wp_verify_nonce return false:

```
main file

<?php

add_action('admin_menu', 'awesome_page_create');
function awesome_page_create() {
    $page_title = 'My Awesome Admin Page';
    $menu_title = 'Awesome Admin Page';
    $capability = 'edit_posts';
    $menu_slug = 'awesome_page';
    $function = 'my_awesome_page_display';
    $icon_url = '';
    $position = 24;

    add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
}
function my_awesome_page_display() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        wp_die('Unauthorized user');
    }

    if (! wp_verify_nonce( '_wp_nonce', 'wpshout_option_page_example_action' )) {
        wp_die('Nonce verification failed');
    }

    if (isset($_POST['awesome_text'])) {
        update_option('awesome_text', $_POST['awesome_text']);
        $value = $_POST['awesome_text'];
    }

    $value = get_option('awesome_text', 'hey-ho');

    include 'form-file.php';
}
$value = get_option('awesome_text');
if (FALSE === $value) {
    $value = 'hey-ho';
}

form-file


<h1>My Awesome Settings Page</h1>

<form method="POST">
    <label for="awesome_text">Awesome Text</label>
    <input type="text" name="awesome_text" id="awesome_text" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
    <?php echo wp_nonce_field( 'wpshout_option_page_example_action' ); ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button button-primary button-large" />
</form>
```

Comment: you need to pass the nonce itself and not the nonce field name, try with `wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_wp_nonce'], 'wpshout_option_page_example_action' )`

Comment: thank you but also it's not work

Answer (score 1):

### Revised code

```
if(is_admin()) {
    add_action('admin_menu', 'awesome_page_create');
    function awesome_page_create() {
        $page_title = 'My Awesome Admin Page';
        $menu_title = 'Awesome Admin Page';
        $capability = 'edit_posts';
        $menu_slug = 'awesome_page';
        $function = 'my_awesome_page_display';
        $icon_url = '';
        $position = 24;
        add_menu_page($page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position);
    }
    function my_awesome_page_display() {
        if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
            wp_die('Unauthorized user');
        }
        $value = get_option('awesome_text', '');
?>
        <h1>My Awesome Settings Page</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            <label for="awesome_text">Awesome Text</label>
            <input type="text" name="awesome_text" id="awesome_text" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
            <?php wp_nonce_field('wpshout_option_page_example_action', 'awesome_nonce', false); ?>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button button-primary button-large" />
        </form>
<?php
    }
    add_action('init', 'process_my_awesome_form_data');
    function process_my_awesome_form_data() {
        if(isset($_REQUEST['awesome_nonce'])) {
            if(wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['awesome_nonce'], 'wpshout_option_page_example_action')) {
                if (isset($_POST['awesome_text'])) {
                    update_option('awesome_text', $_POST['awesome_text']);
                }
            } else {
                echo 'nonce verification failed';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Explanation

`if(is_admin()) {` is to make sure, you're creating admin menu in the right context.

Instead of `include 'form-file.php';`, the form is embedded in `my_awesome_page_display` function, which makes it easier to debug. The line `<?php echo wp_nonce_field( 'wpshout_option_page_example_action' ); ?>` in form's definition was changed to `<?php wp_nonce_field('wpshout_option_page_example_action', 'awsome_nonce', false); ?>`. Your original line was outputting two identical hidden input fields for `nonce`, one, because of `echo`, and second, because the fourth parameter had default value of `true` (which means - print this line).

Don't process your form's submission in `my_awesome_page_display` function. Instead, use `init` hook to add the form's submission processing function `process_my_awsome_form_data`. In that function, `$_REQUEST['awsome_nonce']` is used to retrieve the value of `nonce` for verification, `$_POST['awesome_text']` is used to retrive the value of the text input.

Answer (score -1):

I think for your `wp_nonce_field` you have to use a second parameter (the field name of your custom nonce).

```
<?php echo wp_nonce_field( 'wpshout_option_page_example_action', 'wpshout_option_page_nonce_field' ); ?>
```

Then when you're using your `if` statement for nonce use it :

```
if (! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpshout_option_page_nonce_field'], 'wpshout_option_page_example_action' )) {
    wp_die('Nonce verification failed');
}
```

Try it, I think it's ok :)

Comment: Hum, try to dump and die your $_POST before the if statement of your nonce and show us. Possibly the hook :/

Comment: I have downvoted your answer because you did not test your solution!